# How to print all function calling orders in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to print all function calling orders in a bash script, which is like the call hierarchy in IDEA Intellij?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you don't mean an **accurate** _static call graph_. This is impossible in dynamic languages. How should a function call `func$(foo) a b c`  be represented?

Comment: Since you mentioned the call hierarchy in Intellij, you want a static call graph, right? There are problems like user1934428 mentioned (even though dynamic function names are rather rare. More typical are things like `find -exec` or `eval`). But even with those you could generate a (possibly) incomplete call graph. After all, languages like Java and C have the same problems too. Last year I searched for a call graph generator for bash scripts, couldn't find one, and hacked something together. Maybe I can recycle it for bash functions.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few predefined Bash variables that expose some of this information at runtime, but if you want a statically determined call hierarchy, I'm not aware of any tool that does that for Bash.

Here's how you could find it from the script itself using the predefined arrays `FUNCNAME`, `BASH_LINENO` and `BASH_SOURCE` ([docs](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-FUNCNAME)):

###### callers.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

print_callers() {
  local func file line

  echo 'CALLERS:'

  for i in "${!FUNCNAME[@]}"; do
    # Uncomment next line to skip the current function, i.e., `print_callers`.
    # if [[ $i == 0 ]]; then continue; fi
    func=${FUNCNAME[$i]}
    file=${BASH_SOURCE[$i]}
    line=${BASH_LINENO[$i - 1]}
    echo " - $func ($file:$line)"
  done

  echo
} >&2

baz() {
  print_callers
  echo 'this is a leaf function'
}

bar() {
  baz
}

foo() {
  bar
}

foo
```

The above will output this:

```
$ ./callers.sh
CALLERS:
 - print_callers (./callers.sh:0)
 - baz (./callers.sh:21)
 - bar (./callers.sh:26)
 - foo (./callers.sh:30)
 - main (./callers.sh:33)

this is a leaf function
```

I'm actually using this approach combined with `trap` so that I can print a stacktrace of my script's execution whenever an error is thrown. I have this `prelude.sh` file that I can reuse in different Bash scripts:

###### prelude.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -so errexit
shopt -so errtrace
shopt -so noglob
shopt -so nounset
shopt -so pipefail
shopt -s extglob

bold() {
  tput bold; echo -n "$@"; tput sgr0
}

trap ERR ERR; ERR() {
  local code=$?
  local cmnd=$BASH_COMMAND
  local func file line level

  echo "Exit status $(bold "$code") for command: $(bold "$cmnd")"

  for i in "${!FUNCNAME[@]}"; do
    if [[ $i == 0 ]]; then continue; fi
    func=${FUNCNAME[$i]}
    file=${BASH_SOURCE[$i]}
    line=${BASH_LINENO[$i - 1]}

    if (( i == ${#FUNCNAME[@]} - 1 )); then
      level='└─'
      func="<$func>"
    else
      level='├─'
    fi

    echo " $level $(bold "$func") ($file:$line)"
  done

  exit 1
} >&2
```

Then I can use it like this in my other scripts (`prelude.sh` is on `PATH`):

###### fails.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source prelude.sh

foo() {
  echo '' | grep 'nope'
}

foo
```

And the above will result in this stacktrace being printed out:

```
Exit status 1 for command: grep 'nope'
 ├─ foo (./fails.sh:6)
 └─ <main> (./fails.sh:9)
```